# Wrapping a Non-inheritable class in C#

Tags: c#

I have a simple problem.

I want to decorate the SqlDataReader class so that when the dispose or close methods are called I can dispose of a hidden resource at the same time.

the SqlDataReader class is not inheritable.

How can I accomplish this?  I really don't want to implement the DbDataReader, IDataReader, IDisposable & IDataRecord interfaces

Comment: What do you mean not inheritable? Is it a sealed class? Would you elaborate on the interfaces? Don't you HAVE to implement those? Also, why do you NOT want to?

Comment: SqlDataReader isn't sealed so it's inheritable, but its constructors are private so you cannot satisfy the base constructor when you inherit from it - I'm just nitpicking over details but yet, you're right.

Comment: In addition to my comment on silky's answer, I can't help wondering... what could you possibly need to package with a `SqlDataReader`?  I really hope it's not a `SqlCommand` or `SqlConnection`...

Comment: The resource is an instance of a disposable class.  It is nether a SqlCommand nor a SqlConnection object.  The resource is a Ticket from a Pool of tickets which is being used to guard the resource (Sql DB in this case)

Comment: I hate myself for thinking it, but I wonder if there's a way to put an IL method hook in place to call both the original Close or Dispose in addition to your behaviour. I'm not in the zone to try, but just throwing out an idea.

Comment: Why dont i want to implement the interfaces etc?  Just lazy, also I don't want to inadvertantly introduce bugs ( less code == better )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if you could inherit from SqlDataReader it wouldn't matter anyway because you couldn't make SqlCommand create an instance of your derived class.

Implementing IDataReader in a wrapper is really not hard at all when you're just deferring to the underlying SqlDataReader. It's just a little time consuming but not that bad.

But I'm curious, is the resource you want disposed the connection? If so there is a CloseConnection member of the CommandBehavior enum that ensures the connection will be closed when the data reader is closed.

```
var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
...
reader.Close(); // also closes connection
```

Note that Close/Dispose are the same thing on SqlDataReader.

Finally, here's one last suggestion that has served me well in the past. Note that in the following loose example, you own the SqlDataReader from start to finish even though you are "yielding" back to the caller at each record.

```
private static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> GetResults(this SqlCommand command) {
    using (var myTicket = new MyTicket())
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (reader.Read()) {
            yield return reader;
        }
    }
    // the two resources in the using blocks above will be
    // disposed when the foreach loop below exits
}

...

foreach (var record in myCommand.GetResults()) {

    Console.WriteLine(record.GetString(0));

}

// when the foreach loop above completes, the compiler-generated
// iterator is disposed, allowing the using blocks inside the
// above method to clean up the reader/myTicket objects
```

Comment: The resource is a disposable ticket which is being used to guard access to the SQL Database

Comment: Alright, I added another suggestion in my answer that may help.

Comment: That's a very interesting solution.
What are people's thoughts on this?

Comment: I definitely like the yield solution for the ability to clean up multiple other resources with the reader disposal.

Comment: In fact I just modified the example slightly to enable it as an extension method on SqlCommand. Aside from the resource disposal stuff, foreach just looks cleaner than while (reader.Read())...

Answer (score 3):

Reverse it; use your "Hidden" resource as the main thing, implement IDisposable, and then close the DataReader when you're done with it.

Comment: I'd really rather the calling code didn't know anything about it. It is currently expecting an instance of SqlDataReader

Comment: Do you own the calling code?  Does it really need to accept a `SqlDataReader`?  That's something you should try not to pass around; if you can make it accept an `IDataReader` instead then you can wrap `SqlDataReader` pretty easily.

Comment: Yes I own the calling code.  I'd rather not have to wrap the class (implement IDataReader)

Comment: Harry: Well bad luck. Re-think your design, because what you want isn't possible. It's not logical to get attached to something that is impossible to do. And you don't need to implement `IDataReader`, I'm suggesting you just implement `IDisposable`. Perhaps you should explain, in detail, what you're doing, and we can help with more specific advice.

Comment: This question actually serves as a great example of why it's often better to share interfaces instead of classes, especially heavy system classes - you can easily swap out one implementation for another without changing much code.  More work up front, less down the road.  I wonder what the consuming code is - you might not even need an `IDataReader`, maybe the consumer only uses a couple of methods.  Sorry, don't mean to preach, but silky's right, it's impossible to do as described; time to refactor. :-)

Comment: That's one thing I think they made a big mistake with in the COM -> .NET transition. In COM you only shared interfaces. Even though COM didn't deal with implementation inheritence, it didn't matter because you could always aggregate.

Comment: So i ended up doing this.  but i gave Josh Einstein's answer the tick because i really liked his solution

Answer (score 1):

<strike>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx
The class is is not sealed. You should just be able to call base.dispose() at the start of your override and then put your code after.</strike>

I dont have my IDE in front of me but it should look somthing like

```
public myClass : SqlDataReader
{
    protected overide void Dispose(bool disposing) : Base(disposing)
    {
        myCleanupCode();
    }
    protected overide void Dispose()
    {
        myCleanupCode();
    }
    private myCleanupCode()
    {
        //Do cleanup here so you can make one change that will apply to both cases.
    }
}
```

EDIT---
just read the orginal comments, i see that it has the private constructor, let me break out my VS2008 and ill brb

looking in to it, and everyone is trying these fancy solutions, the only thing I see that can be done is

```
public class myClass : IDisposable
{

    public SqlDataReader dataReader { get; set; }

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        dataReader.Dispose();
        //My dispose code
    }

    #endregion
}
```

EDIT--- Sigh, this is excatly what Silky posted 40 min ago.

Comment: This code causes the COMPILE ERRORS: Error#1 The type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' has no constructors defined... and ... Error#2 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.SqlDataReader(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand, System.Data.CommandBehavior)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: first line of your link: "This class cannot be inherited."

Comment: Might as well pass back a Tuple of <SqlDataReader, Ticket>

Comment: @Harry As long as Ticket implements Idisposable that may be your best option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Decorator pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern) to wrap an instance of `SqlDataReader`. You would have to implement the public "interface" of it though and use your Decorator in place of the `SqlDataReader`. You can just forward the method calls on your Decorator to the wrapped `SqlDataReader`. To go this route you would need to be using interfaces (with your own implementation) that provides the database command, etc. I had to do something similar for mocking my database implementation for unit testing. It is a little work but it can be done.